# Google Cloud Storageから画像を引っ張ってこようとすると「faild to load resource the server responded with a status of 403」と表示される

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-storage

現在以下のようにGoogle Cloud Storageにある画像のフルパスを取得しています。

```
$disk = Storage::disk('gcp');
$url = $disk->url('test.jpg');
```

そしてその取得したurlをimgタグに流し込んでいるのですが、画像が表示されません。
なのでソースを表示して、imgタグに表示されたURLにアクセスしようとすると、「faild to load resource the server responded with a status of 403」と表示されてしまいます。
色々調べているとGoogle Cloud Storageにアクセスする権限を追加しないといけないようなのですが、どうやって権限を追加すればいいか分かりません。
Google Cloud PlatformのコンソールのStorage -> 設定 ->プロジェクト アクセスにはIDがあり、これらを使うのではないかと思っているのですが、どうやって設定すればいいか分かりません。
権限を付与してGoogle Cloud Storageから画像を引っ張れるようにするにはどうすればいいでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Storageの認証方式はいくつかあるので、どのようなユースケースでの利用を想定しているかで少し変わります。
とりあえず、一番簡単そうなものを書いておきます。

GCPの権限としては、アカウントとPermissionの組み合わせがあります。
アカウントは二種類あり、Googleアカウントとサービスアカウントがあります。
おそらくGCPではないどこかのマシンで動かすのではないかと思うので、その場合はサービスアカウントを利用します。
まず、 https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication?hl=ja#service_accounts の手順に従って、サービスアカウントを作成して、 `secret.json` をダウンロードします。
その時に、サービスアカウントのPermissionとして、Storage Adminを指定してください。Storage Adminは強い権限なので、必要に応じて権限を調整してください。

その後、 https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account?hl=ja を利用して、サービスアカウントでログインした状態を作ります。 --key-file でダウンロードした `secret.json` を指定すればOKです。

ユースケースをもう少し詳しく書いてもらえると、また違った方式がベストになるかもしれませんので、どこで動かすのか？だれがアクセスできて、だれがアクセスできないのか？などを教えてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
まずサービスアカウントを作成して、jsonファイルをダウンロードしました。しかしサービスアカウントの「権限」ボタンをクリックして役割を追加しようとしてもStorage Adminが見当たりませんでした...。
結局見つからなかったので一旦「gcloud auth activate-service-account [ACCOUNT] --key-file=KEY_FILE」を実行したのですが、「Unable to read file [xxx.json]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory」と怒られてしまいました。ACCOUNTにはサービスアカウント名をいれ、KEY_FILEには先ほどダウンロードしたjsonファイルを入れました。

僕がやりたいことを詳しく書くと、以下のようになります。
ユーザーが記事に画像を追加して投稿すると、Cloud Storageに画像を保存し、ユーザーが記事を見ようとするとCloud Storageから画像を持ってこようとしています。
まず、プロジェクトはLaravelで作成しており、LaravelのFileSystemを使ってクラウドとの画像のやり取りを行おうとしています。

Comment: そしてAWSのS3用ドライバをGoogle Cloud Storageでも使えるようにGoogle Cloud PlatformのStorageの設定で相互運用できるようにしました。
そして画像のアップロードは成功したのですが、ダウンロードができていません。
試しに画像へのURLにアクセスすると表題の通りのエラーが表示されるといった状況です。

Comment: gcloud auth activate-service-account [ACCOUNT] --key-file=KEY_FILEがNo such file or directoryになったのは、おそらくFullPathを指定すれば動くのではないかと思います。

Comment: Laravelを介してアップロードが成功しているのであれば、Laravelが利用しているサービスアカウントはStorageの権限を持っていると思います。そうなると、ダウンロードに失敗する理由がよく分からないですね。一度、Cloud StorageのFileをPublicにしてみて、それでも失敗するのであればCloud StorageのIAMではなくLaravelのレイヤーで拒否されている気がします。

Comment: jsonファイルのフルパスを指定すると、Activated service account credentials for: [myproject@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
と表示されました。これで自由にバケットにアクセスできるようになったということでしょうか？しかしバケット一覧を取得するコマンド「gsutil ls」を入力すると「AccessDeniedException: 403」と表示されてしまいます...。そしてクラウドの画像へのURLにアクセスすると、「Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to xxx.jpg」と表示されています。なので取得したい画像をコンソール上で一般公開で共有するにチェックしました。画像の権限を見ても僕のメールアドレスがオーナーになっています。確かにアップロードができてダウンロードができないのはちょっと不思議ですね...。

Comment: Activated service account credentialsはそのサービスアカウントでのログインに成功したというだけなので、権限は付与されていません。Cloud ConsoleのIAMから次の手順で設定してあげてください https://drive.google.com/file/d/16FGdmfXex3Ov6WDu8sI9Mu3r3_mDzpiJ/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/17NaZdrn1P0KpDQZ9qI6ZOTTWhtZ28_sl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: 画像の権限が自分のメールアドレスになっているということは、その画像は自分のアカウントでアップロードしたものになっているということですね。アップロードしているアカウントとダウンロードしようとしているアカウントが異なっているのかもしれません。

Comment: ご提示いただいた画像の通り、権限を付与しました。ここで一つ疑問に思ったのですが、付与するアカウントは「myproject@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com」というアカウントで良かったでしょうか？もう一つ権限を付与できるGoogleのアカウント「myaddress@gmail.com」があったのですが、これはどちらでもいいのでしょうか？役割は二つとも最初からオーナーになっていました。とりあえず今は「myproject@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com」にストレージ管理者を追加しています。

Comment: アップロードしているアカウントとダウンロードしようとしているアカウントが異なっているとのことですが、アップロードしようとしているアカウントはどこで確認すればいいでしょうか？Laravelのfilesystem.phpのkeyやsecretを見ても分かりませんでした...。また、ダウンロードしようとしているアカウントもどう確認すればいいか分かりません。すみません、本当に初心者で分からないことだらけで申し訳ないです...。

Comment: 私はLaravelもPHPも知らないので、残念ながらLaravelがどのようにCloud Storageを利用しているのかはよく分かりません。以下のいずれかのやり方だと思っていますが、どれなのかは分からないです。

Comment: 1. myproject@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com をLaravelが利用して、Cloud Storageにアップロード・ダウンロードする。

この場合は、 `myproject@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com` がCloud Storageのストレージ管理者を持っていれば問題ありません。権限管理をLaravelのアプリケーションで行う時によくある方式です。

Comment: 2. アップロードはLaravelがmyproject@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.comを利用して行うが、ダウンロードはCloud Storageから直接ダウンロードする

この場合は、 `myproject@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com` がCloud Storageのストレージ管理者を持っていると共に、ダウンロードを行う人がCloud Storageのオブジェクト閲覧者の権限を持っている必要があります。Blogなどを公開する時は全世界のみんなが見える必要があるので、Cloud StorageのオブジェクトそのものをPublicにします。

Comment: 何をやっても全く画像がダウンロードできません。せっかく親身に教えていただいたので申し訳ないです。自分のプログラミングの才能のなさに辟易してきたので、一旦休みます。また再開することがあればまた違った視点で考えれるかもしれないので、その時にまた試してみたいと思います。すみません。色々と丁寧に方法を教えていただき誠にありがとうございました。

Comment: できました！今までどうやらフォルダが保存されていたようで、以下のようにfile_get_contentsを使うことで画像を保存でき、画像をダウンロードできるようになりました。
$disk = Storage::disk('gcp');
$disk->put($fileName, file_get_contents($image));
今まではフォルダをダウンロードしようとしていたからうまくいっていなかったのだと思います。
お手数をおかけしましたが無事やりたいことが実現できました。ありがとうございました。